# How to view an ArrayList in a horizonal scrollbar?

Tags: java, android

I have this `mEpisodeList` which is an ArrayList inside this class `TvShowEpisodeLoader`
I also have another class named `TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment`
I want to access `mEpisodeList`from `TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment`
I want to get `mEpisode` (which is the number of the episodes of a season of a tv show)
and display all available episode numbers in a horizonal scrollbar  in `episode_details` layout and upon tapping on a number it will switch to that episode

here is [TvShowEpisodeLoader](https://pastebin.com/p8NWACNL) , [TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment](https://pastebin.com/VyRQrQH8)

[mEpisodeList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF3l5.jpg)

here is the code

```
import com.miz.loader.TvShowEpisodeLoader;
@SuppressLint("InflateParams") public class TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
private TvShowEpisodeLoader.TvShowEpisodeLoaderAsyncTask tab3 = new TvShowEpisodeLoader.TvShowEpisodeLoaderAsyncTask() {
        mEpisodeList = new ArrayList<GridEpisode>();
    };
```

```
private class TvShowEpisodeLoaderAsyncTask extends LibrarySectionAsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final ArrayList<GridEpisode> mEpisodeList;

        public TvShowEpisodeLoaderAsyncTask() {
            mEpisodeList = new ArrayList<GridEpisode>();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            mEpisodeList.addAll(MizuuApplication.getTvEpisodeDbAdapter()
                    .getEpisodesInSeason(mContext, getShowId(), getShowSeason()));

            int totalSize = mEpisodeList.size();

            switch (getWatchedFilter()) {
                case WATCHED:
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++) {
                        if (!mEpisodeList.get(i).hasWatched()) {
                            mEpisodeList.remove(i);
                            i--;
                            totalSize--;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case UNWATCHED:
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++) {
                        if (mEpisodeList.get(i).hasWatched()) {
                            mEpisodeList.remove(i);
                            i--;
                            totalSize--;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }

            if (showAvailableFiles()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++) {
                    ArrayList<FileSource> filesources = MizLib.getFileSources(MizLib.TYPE_SHOWS, true);

                    if (isCancelled())
                        return null;

                    boolean condition = false;

                    for (Filepath path : mEpisodeList.get(i).getFilepaths()) {
                        if (path.isNetworkFile())
                            if (FileUtils.hasOfflineCopy(mContext, path)) {
                                condition = true;
                                break; // break inner loop to continue to the next episode
                            } else {
                                if (path.getType() == FileSource.SMB) {
                                    if (MizLib.isWifiConnected(mContext)) {
                                        FileSource source = null;

                                        for (int j = 0; j < filesources.size(); j++)
                                            if (path.getFilepath().contains(filesources.get(j).getFilepath())) {
                                                source = filesources.get(j);
                                                break;
                                            }

                                        if (source == null)
                                            continue;

                                        try {
                                            final SmbFile file = new SmbFile(
                                                    MizLib.createSmbLoginString(
                                                            source.getDomain(),
                                                            source.getUser(),
                                                            source.getPassword(),
                                                            path.getFilepath(),
                                                            false
                                                    ));
                                            if (file.exists()) {
                                                condition = true;
                                                break; // break inner loop to continue to the next episode
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                        }  // Do nothing - the file isn't available (either MalformedURLException or SmbException)
                                    }
                                } else if (path.getType() == FileSource.UPNP) {
                                    if (MizLib.exists(path.getFilepath())) {
                                        condition = true;
                                        break; // break inner loop to continue to the next episode
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        else {
                            if (new File(path.getFilepath()).exists()) {
                                condition = true;
                                break; // break inner loop to continue to the next episode
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (!condition && mEpisodeList.size() > i) {
                        mEpisodeList.remove(i);
                        i--;
                        totalSize--;
                    }
                }
            }

            Collections.sort(mEpisodeList, getSortType().getComparator());

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (!isCancelled()) {
                mResults = new ArrayList<>(mEpisodeList);
                mCallback.onLoadCompleted();
            } else
                mEpisodeList.clear();
        }
    }
```

this one  is from `TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment`

```
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mBackdrop = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageBackground);
        mEpisodePhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.episodePhoto);
        mDetailsArea = view.findViewById(R.id.details_area);

        mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
        mSeasonEpisodeNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        mDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mFileSource = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        mAirDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textReleaseDate);
        mRating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        mDirector = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.director);
        mWriter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.writer);
        mGuestStars = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.guest_stars);
        mScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.observableScrollView);
        mFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);

        mFab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewUtils.animateFabJump(v, new SimpleAnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        play();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        if (MizLib.isTablet(mContext))
            mFab.setType(FloatingActionButton.TYPE_NORMAL);

        final int height = MizLib.getActionBarAndStatusBarHeight(getActivity());

        mScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.observableScrollView);
        mScrollView.setOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged(ScrollView who, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
                final int headerHeight = mEpisodePhoto.getHeight() - height;
                final float ratio = (float) Math.min(Math.max(t, 0), headerHeight) / headerHeight;
                final int newAlpha = (int) (ratio * 255);

                mBus.post(new BusToolbarColorObject(mToolbarColor, newAlpha));

                if (MizLib.isPortrait(mContext)) {
                    // Such parallax, much wow
                    mEpisodePhoto.setPadding(0, (int) (t / 1.5), 0, 0);
                }
            }
        });
        mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ViewUtils.setLayoutParamsForDetailsEmptyView(mContext, view,
                        mBackdrop, mScrollView, this);
            }
        });

        loadData();

        mPicasso.load(mEpisode.getEpisodePhoto()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg).config(MizuuApplication.getBitmapConfig()).into(mEpisodePhoto, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onError() {
                if (!isAdded())
                    return;
                int width = getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.episode_details_background_overlay_width);
                int height = getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.episode_details_background_overlay_height);
                mPicasso.load(mEpisode.getTvShowBackdrop()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg).error(R.drawable.nobackdrop).resize(width, height).config(MizuuApplication.getBitmapConfig()).into(mEpisodePhoto);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if (mPaletteLoader == null) {
                    mPaletteLoader = new PaletteLoader(mPicasso, Uri.fromFile(mEpisode.getEpisodePhoto()), new PaletteLoader.OnPaletteLoadedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPaletteLoaded(int swatchColor) {
                            mToolbarColor = swatchColor;
                        }
                    });

                    mPaletteLoader.addView(mDetailsArea);
                    mPaletteLoader.setFab(mFab);

                    mPaletteLoader.execute();
                } else {
                    // Clear old views after configuration change
                    mPaletteLoader.clearViews();

                    // Add views after configuration change
                    mPaletteLoader.addView(mDetailsArea);
                    mPaletteLoader.setFab(mFab);

                    // Re-color the views
                    mPaletteLoader.colorViews();
                }
            }
        });

        if (!MizLib.isPortrait(getActivity()))
            mPicasso.load(mEpisode.getEpisodePhoto()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg).error(R.drawable.bg).transform(new BlurTransformation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mEpisode.getEpisodePhoto().getAbsolutePath() + "-blur", 4)).into(mBackdrop, new Callback() {
                @Override public void onError() {
                    if (!isAdded())
                        return;

                    mPicasso.load(mEpisode.getTvShowBackdrop()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg).error(R.drawable.nobackdrop).transform(new BlurTransformation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mEpisode.getTvShowBackdrop().getAbsolutePath() + "-blur", 4)).into(mBackdrop, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {}

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            if (!isAdded())
                                return;
                            mBackdrop.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#aa181818"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    if (!isAdded())
                        return;
                    mBackdrop.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#aa181818"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Hello. Could you add some sample code in the question? screenshots are much useful when we want to recreate the problem etc.

Comment: Thanks, I attched both of my classes now, I want to clarify that mEpisodeList is inisde TvShowEpisodeLoaderAsyncTask class which is inside TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment

Comment: I can't seem to reach pastebin for some reason. I appreciate If you could add your code into the question and format it.

Comment: OK I updated now

Comment: I'm able to see TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment  on pastebin via vpn right now. These two classes are not connected in anyway.  is there TvShowEpisodeLoader  ref inside TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment  ? Or vice-versa?  You need make connections between the classes a bit more clear.

Comment: You are right they are not connected , but I imported TvShowEpisodeLoader   import com.miz.loader.TvShowEpisodeLoader; from within TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment

Comment: I want to get data from TvShowEpisodeLoader  to be viewed inside TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment

Comment: I tried some methods but I couldn't comprehend very well, so now I'm back to zero

Comment: Show the code line in TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment  which you use TvShowEpisodeLoader  ref. Because when I search for "TvShowEpisodeLoader " in TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment   , I get nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post now can you see it, I created an instance of the class , is it wrong?

Comment: I made TvShowEpisodeLoaderAsyncTask public

Comment: (part 1)I'm gonna shoot blind here. Let's see if it'll be useful for you.  

 Inside TvShowEpisodeLoaderAsyncTask class , add this method:  
public ArrayList<GridEpisode> getAsyncEpisodeList() 
{
          return  mEpisodeList ;
 }

Comment: (part2 ) 
Inside TvShowEpisodeLoader class  add this method:  
     
public ArrayList<GridEpisode> getEpisodeList() 
{
          return  mAsyncTask.getAsyncEpisodeList();
}

Comment: (part 3) 
Inside the TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment  class : 
import com.miz.loader.TvShowEpisodeLoader;

private TvShowEpisodeLoader tvShowEpisodeLoader;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
tvShowEpisodeLoader=new tvShowEpisodeLoader(mContext ,   showId,   showSeason,   callback) ;


private void loadEpisode() {
...
ArrayList<GridEpisode>  episodelist = tvShowEpisodeLoader.getEpisodeList();

Comment: comment starting as part 3 , shows a code accessing that list from within TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment

Comment: Ok I will do this, I really appreciate your help, I will get back to you with my results

Comment: Hopefully either it works or it gives you an idea to go on with.

Comment: Here is a pseudo code in java :   https://www.online-ide.com/KoIgX51HMw  with classes simplified.

Comment: Much appreciated, god bless you

Comment: thanks after implementing it I cannot seem to resolve these https://imgur.com/aC3REZU

Comment: when you move your cursor over that parts, what is the error message showing up? Also showSeason, callback are shown in deep red font. Where do you get these values? I wrote them in pseudo code for you to replace them with their real counterparts which you would acquire them within TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment class somehow

Comment: I hope you  forgive me for the late reply , here is what I get when I hover over them https://imgur.com/4QBWMIr , https://imgur.com/7SwyrSc

Comment: Now after correcting the issues I get this error https://imgur.com/v8MOENu

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Can debug the code and see if that variable is being initialized ?  it shouldnt be null.  the line inside onCreate(), that variable should be initialized.

Comment: No problem sir, I will provide  a debug code

Comment: [here is debug log](https://pastebin.com/JZc8bDMb)

Comment: Hello, Sorry for the late reply. I used vpn to see pastebin, it's blocked in my country for some reason. Anyhow,  exception log doesn't tell anything new. Somehow   tvShowEpisodeLoader  variable is not initialized and it is null at the moment of the call  "tvShowEpisodeLoader.getEpisodeList()".  Please check your code to find if the method   "onCreate()"  within the class TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment is called at all?  I gave you the link to some pseudo code https://www.online-ide.com/KoIgX51HMw  In there, I added a line to "onCreate()", : tvShowEpisodeLoader=new tvShowEpisodeLoader(...) ; 1/2

Comment: Please check that you have this line in "oncreate()" method 2/2

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem in a different way , you are right it was not initialized , so the the same ArrayList that I needed was available in another class called TvShowEpisode.java  so I imported and initialized properly , and now my got my scroll bar to work properly

Comment: can you help out with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67926058/i-need-help-to-handle-touch-events-of-a-recyclerview-items

Comment: Are you guys working on the same project :D

Comment: yes please it is the same project , we really really need some help , we can't get onclick events working on the recyclerview scroll bar  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67926058/i-need-help-to-handle-touch-events-of-a-recyclerview-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by importing the `ArrayList` from another class called `TvShowEpisode` instead of `GridEpisode` and Initialized properly
Huge thanks to [AntiqTech]

here is what I did

the Arraylist was ready to be called so all I needed was

```
private ArrayList<TvShowEpisode> mEpisodes = new ArrayList<TvShowEpisode>();
private static final String SHOW_ID = "showId";
```

```
   
            mShowId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(SHOW_ID);
    
            Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getEpisodes(mShowId);
            try {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    mEpisodes.add(new TvShowEpisode(mContext, mShowId,
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_TITLE)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_PLOT)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SEASON)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_AIRDATE)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_DIRECTOR)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_WRITER)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_GUESTSTARS)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_RATING)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_HAS_WATCHED)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_FAVOURITE))
                    ));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
```

```
    // populating the listview
            mEpisodesList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.episodesList);
    
            ArrayList<String> episodeslist = new ArrayList<String>(mEpisodes.size()); //set initialize capacity as it's know, some negligible performance related reason
    
            for(TvShowEpisode e : mEpisodes){
                episodeslist.add(e.mEpisode);
            }
    
            // Create The Adapter
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, episodeslist);
            // Set The Adapter
            mEpisodesList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

the xml

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/hsv"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:measureAllChildren="false"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/episodesList"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Glad you were able to reach a solution.

Comment: Thanks to you, I appreciate your help, you put me on the right path.